# Reverse SSH on Windows Git BASH

Tags: windows, bash, ssh, git, rsync

I have multiples Windows 10 computer where I **can't** open anymore ports, neither install more software. But those computers have git bash installed on it.

I would like to be able to run some bash script on them to synchronize some folders with `rsync`.  I can't execute the command directly from them as it isn't installed by default with git bash.

But the remote server have the `rsync` command available. So I was wondering if is it possible to create a script on the server that will allow me to connect back to the local machine (**without** sshd running) to synchronize the folder ?

something like

`local_computer> ssh remote_server './synchronize-folder.sh'`

```
# /synchronize-folder.sh

rsync /remote/folder/to/synchronize localhost@43022:/local/folder
```

PS: I don't have access to `sshfs` on those local Windows, neither.

Comment: AFAIK you need to have `rsync` on both sides anyway.

Comment: Have GIT bash isn’t enough to SSH into a machine you have to configure OpenSSH Server (properly) which requires full elevated system administrator permissions to do so. What you want is impossible without sshd